# How to get microphone working on WSL Ubuntu 20..04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, windows-subsystem-for-linux, microphone

I'm a windows user trying to create a shazam-like app in python with WSL Ubuntu. The app worked perfectly fine. But when I wanted to test the app whether it can detect the songs I'm playing from my phone, It can't. I think it's because WSL can't get the microphone.

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks!